# batch class is failing due to time while processing SOQL due to timeout error

Tags: soql, batch, dynamic-soql, schedulebatch

Hi batch class is failing due to time while processing SOQL in start method due to timeout error the query is:

```
query= 'Select id from customObject__c where deal_Expires_On__c < = today and Registration_Status__c 
   in (\'Accepted\') and opportunity__r.stageName not in (\'Won\',\'Closed/Lost\') ';
```

Please help me to optimize this query. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things you can do to improve the performance of your SOQL query.  The most effective will be to understand how to diagnose it yourself, because how to solve your issue depends on what those fields are.
e.g. Are any of those fields formula fields?  If so, the only way the query engine can filter by that field is via a table scan.

The Salesforce help is fantastic for this kind of thing, especially: [Make SOQL query selective](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-make-my-SOQL-query-selective)

The key takeaways for you from that help article are:

- **deal_Expires_On__c < = today** won't be selective
- **opportunity__r.stageName != ((\'Won\') OR (\'Closed/Lost\'))** won't be selective
- **Registration_Status__c 
  = (\'Accepted\')** may be selective, depending on your data

There is also the [Improving Performance by Not Searching on Null Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_filtering_nulls.htm) part of the apex dev guide.

My recommendations are:

- Get familiar with the query editor in the developer console. You may need to turn the Query Plan on by going to Help > Preferences > Enable Query Plan
- add checks for nulls in your query.  i.e. `eal_Expires_On__c != null`, `Registration_Status__c`, and `opportunity__r.stageName != null`.
- try not to query based on the value not being something.  i.e. can `opportunity__r.stageName != ((\'Won\') OR (\'Closed/Lost\'))` be changed to `opportunity__r.stageName = ((\'Some value\')`?

Comment: there are no formula fields,
deal_Expires_On__c is a date field
stageName and Registration_Status__c  are picklist 

Can you please explain, what do you mean by selective soql query

Answer (score 3):

For starters, `today` should be written as `today()`. You have other syntax errors as well where you're using `in` instead of `=` since those aren't lists, but instead values. Looks like you're also missing an `OR`. I think you need to rewrite it as below:

```
querystring = 'Select id from customObject__c where deal_Expires_On__c < = today() && Registration_Status__c 
    = (\'Accepted\') && opportunity__r.stageName != ((\'Won\') OR (\'Closed/Lost\')) ';
```

Comment: TODAY is a `Date Literal`, it is not a syntax error.  Using `IN ('Accepted')` is also valid and Salesforce treats it as a List with a single value.  `IN ('Won', 'Closed Lost')` is treated as a List with two values.

Comment: Yeah you're getting context confused between dynamic queries and merge fields.

Comment: @DougB Thanks for the correction. Love it when I learn something new! :) I thought it was a means of escaping a value. Will have to look at the dynamic SOQL documentation a bit further to see what I've been overlooking.